# Eclipse Oxygen - projects disappear

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

Why do projects disappear from the project explorer in Oxygen?  I can see them briefly after starting Eclipse but then they disappear.

They can't be re-added or imported because it says they already exist.

I re-cloned the project from git into a different directory, deleted .classpath, .settings and .project and tried to import as a file system but can't advance.  The next button is greyed out.

Import projects from folder or archive allowed me to import my clone but then it dissappears again. I know it's there because if I select build, I see my newly added project and other projects that have disappeared.

Comment: What do you mean by disappeared? Not visible in Package/Project Explorer? Maybe the projects are only hidden by the current "Working Set" or by "Focus on Active Task".

Comment: Yeah it was hidden.  I never selected a working set though.  It's a relatively fresh install.  Confused ... maybe a setting came though when I cloned it but it's been a few days so why not earlier if that was the case.  Anyway thanks.

Comment: Great, I added it as answer.

Comment: See also: [Eclipse Mars - imported projects don't show up in Project/Enterprise Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45465437/4561887)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably, the projects are only hidden by the active *[Working Set](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-48b.htm)* or by *[Focus on Active Task](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.mylyn.help.ui/Mylyn/User_Guide/Task-Focused-Interface.html)*.